# How do I press the Windows key from a Mac running a Citrix session on a Windows host?

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard, citrix

For example, I wish to perform Windows+E to open the Windows file explorer in the Windows environment running over Citrix from my Mac.  The Citrix-Online-Plugin-for-Macintosh-Administrators-Guide [1] talks about other special keys but says nothing about the Windows key.  I was somewhat surprised that google searches didn't readily identify any discussion about this topic.  Perhaps I just don't have the right keywords?

[1] http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/21054-102-511118/Citrix-Online-Plugin-for-Macintosh-Administrators-Guide.pdf

Comment: Did you try pressing Command-E? When I'm using a virtual machine on my Mac, it interprets the Command key as a Windows key. Similarly, when I boot into Windows using Bootcamp, pressing Command works as a Windows key.

Answer (score 5):

Specifically, the right-hand Command key works for me. The left-hand one seems to simply emulate the Ctrl key.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Citrix help document](http://support.citrixonline.com/GoToMyPC/all_files/GTC070002) you would simply press Command-E.